# PHP: Replace 1st char in a string - to create a link to itself

Tags: php

In my **test.php** I would like to provide a link back to the production script **index.php**, passing the same GET-parameters:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
        $get .= "&$key=$val";
}
# this one is wrong - I want to replace just the first "&"
$get = str_replace("&", "?", $get);

echo '<p>You are viewing the test version.</p>

<p><a href="/index.php' . $get .
'">Return to production version</a></p>';
```

How do I replace just the 1st char in the `$get` string?

Or maybe there is a nicer way to create a "self-link"?

Comment: You may be interested in: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, which contains the query string from the request, except for the first `?` charater.

So, for instance, if you were to go to http://example.com/page.php?var1=val1&var2=val2, the contents of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` would be `var1=val1&var2=val2`

Also, to replace the first character of the string, you can simply use:

```
if(strlen($string) > 0) // Unexpected behavior would occur with empty strings
{
  $string[0] = '?'; // This would modify the first character of a string
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 3):

You could just do:

```
$get = 'index.php?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$get = preg_replace('/&/', '?', $get, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$get = "";

foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
    $get .= "&$key=$val";
}
if(strlen($get) > 0)
    $get[0] = "?";
```